# How to run postbooks server in Ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql

I installed post-book accounting software from Ubuntu software center in 14.04 LTS. Also installed post-book demo database and PostgreSQL. But I cannot able to run the post-book server. How can I setup user and password for this?

Comment: Postbooks available on Ubuntu 14.04 software center.

Comment: is this sufficient? or not what you wanted to see?

Comment: I also read the github documentation, then what is the purpose of the postbooks package in ubuntu software center?

Comment: From what I saw the one in USC needs -specific- vBox and  Vragrant installation but it does not tell you which one you need. Useless ... I got it working only from the github version. I can try a 2nd time and focus on the USC version if you want (but the HELP button on that one sent me to the website that told me the github one is free and the others are just trials).

Answer (score 3):

Login  credentials are:

> Username: admin
>
> Password: admin
>
> Server : 192.168.33.10
>
> Port: 5432
>
> Database: demo

---

BUT! You need to install the github version if you want to use the **free** version. The instructions for the free version are:

- install [virtualBox 4.3](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3)
- install [vagrant 1.5.4](http://www.vagrantup.com/download-archive/v1.5.4.html)

Comments:

- Both installed in 14.04 without a problem
- Do not open VirtualBox or create a virtual machine. This will be handled by Vagrant.
- Use the Vagrant download page. Package managers like apt-get and gem install will install an older version of Vagrant.
- This installation requires a reboot before any Vagrant commands can be performed

---

After installation and a reboot you need to create a config file in any place you want (I prefer my home) with:

```
cd ~/
mkdir xtuple-demo
cd xtuple-demo
vagrant init xtuple/xtuple-mobile
```

Result from the last command:

> A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on `vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.

Create and start the xTuple server:

```
vagrant up
```

Result:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'xtuple/xtuple-mobile' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'xtuple/xtuple-mobile'
    default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/xtuple/xtuple-mobile
==> default: Adding box 'xtuple/xtuple-mobile' (v4.4.1.1) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/xtuple/xtuple-mobile/version/4/provider/virtualbox.box
    default: Progress: 5% (Rate: 1965k/s, Estimated time remaining: 0:09:41)
```

(this will take a while; took an hour to finish when I did this).

At the end is shows:

```
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /home/rinzwind/xtuple-demon
```

After the server has finished loading, launch your local browser and navigate to the application: `http://localhost:8888`. Result:

[image]

and admin/admin logs me in:

[image]

I used this [source](https://github.com/xtuple/xtuple/wiki/How-to-set-up-xTuple) to install and test.

---

The software in Ubuntu software center seems to be just a connector to their (non free) cloud based software. I have not seen software that allows you to run your own instance locally (ie. localhost) unless you use the method above (the virtualbox container using vagrant). The method you use (software from USC with Postgress fails because you still need apache to host the system and the software that is their website. That last one is not free and not available).

Answer (score 0):

There are three moving parts to keep track of with our application (I work for xTuple).

First is the xTuple Server. Rinzwind did a great job of explaining how to set up an xTuple Server using vagrant. For production use, we don't recommend Vagrant. The full documentation on the xTuple Server is here:
https://github.com/xtuple/xtuple-server/wiki

The second moving part is the web client. You get this automatically with the server. Just point your browser where Rinzwind noted, and you can use the app.

The third moving part is our desktop application, which is older and more fully-featured. *That's* what you're finding on the USC. The desktop client complements the web client, and can connect to the same interoperable database using the same login credentials. The problem with our desktop application on USC is that it's out of date; it's on 4.1, whereas our latest release is 4.6 and the xTuple server probably won't build anything before 4.4.

The easiest way to grab the latest desktop client is to grab it off of sourceforge.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/postbooks/files/02%20PostBooks-GUIclient-only/

It's not quite right to say that any of our clients only work in the cloud or on a locally-hosted environment. The xTuple Server works in the cloud, or locally, and both the desktop client and the web client can connect to either one.